# Usage of 'pull' command in Jgit

Tags: java, git, git-pull, jgit

I'm a new user of git and am using [JGit](http://wiki.eclipse.org/JGit) to interact with a remote git repository. In JGit, I used `CloneCommand` to initially to clone a repo, and it worked without a issue. However, when I try to use `PullCommand`, which is the equivalent of SVN update AFAIK, the local repo contents are not updated.

This is the code that I used:

```
private String localPath;
private Repository localRepo;
private Git git;

localPath = "/home/test/git_repo_test";
remotePath = "https://github.com/test/repo_1.git";

try {
    localRepo = new FileRepository(localPath + "/.git");
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();  
}
git = new Git(localRepo);

PullCommand pullCmd = git.pull();
try {
    pullCmd.call();
} catch (GitAPIException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();  
}
```

This doesn't update the local repository for new files which I have pushed to the remote repository using the command line. However, if I delete the local repository and take a clone again, all the changes are reflected.

Please let me know what is the correct approach of using `PullCommand` in JGit.

EDIT:

The structure of the remote repository:

```
root ____ file_1
  |______ directory_1
              |__________ file_2 
              |__________ file_3
```

directory_1 and the two files are pushed from the commandline after the initial cloning and I tried this code so that it will get reflected in the local repository, which is not happening.

The code used to clone the repository:

```
File file = new File(localPath);
CloneCommand cloneCmd = git.cloneRepository();
try {
    cloneCmd.setURI(remotePath)
            .setDirectory(file)
            .call();
} catch (GitAPIException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();  
}
```

Here, `git`, `localPath` and `remotePath` are the same variable as above.

Comment: Could you include the code you used to clone the repository?

Answer (score 9):

I suspect the problem is that the current branch has no upstream configuration (and so pull won't merge the fetched branch).

To see what happened during the pull, inspect the result of `pullCmd.call()`:

```
PullResult result = pullCmd.call();
FetchResult fetchResult = result.getFetchResult();
MergeResult mergeResult = result.getMergeResult();
mergeResult.getMergeStatus();  // this should be interesting
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggesstion. Result of getMergeStatus.isSuccessful()  is true. However, still the changes are not reflected locally. Any idea?

Comment: What is the status? It should be `FAST_FORWARD`. Also, have you looked at the cloned repository using the command-line git client, does it look alright (e.g. `git status`)?

Comment: I checked it, it says ALREADY_UP_TO_DATE. Guess this is the issue then. But somehow the files from the remote repository are not updated. And git status says on branch master, and shows some files that  have deleted earlier.

Answer (score 4):

Documentations says about constructor of `Git` class following:

> Constructs a new Git object which can interact with the specified git repository. All command classes returned by methods of this class will always interact with this git repository.

So, as I can suggest, you have to pass path of remote repo to constructor, now you're trying to pull from your local repo.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue. For me the solution was to set the git config file after cloning:

```java
CloneCommand cloneCommand = Git.cloneRepository();
cloneCommand.setURI("<repo-uri>");
cloneCommand.setDirectory("<repo-dir>");
cloneCommand.call();

Git git = Git.open("<repo-dir>");
StoredConfig config = git.getRepository().getConfig();
config.setString("branch", "master", "merge", "refs/heads/master");
config.setString("branch", "master", "remote", "origin");
config.setString("remote", "origin", "fetch", "+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*");
config.setString("remote", "origin", "url", "<repo-uri>");
config.save();
```

When pulling I set the remote branch name to "master" and the remote to "origin":

```java
PullCommand pull = git.pull();
pull.setRemote("origin");
pull.setRemoteBranchName("master");
```

With these changes after pulling I see the changes reflected locally.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code for git pull from private Repository

```
try {
        Repository localRepo = new FileRepository(localPath + "/.git");
        Git git = new Git(localRepo);
        CredentialsProvider cp = new UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider(userName, pass);
        git.pull().setCredentialsProvider(cp).call();
        git.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
```