# How can I download a pull request from a private repo?

Tags: java, github, jgit

I want to download the pull request from a private repo, that I have token, using java.

Reading the Jgit, I didn't find a way.

Does anyone have an idea about this ?

Comment: It seems to be duplicated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13399990/usage-of-pull-command-in-jgit)

Answer (score 0):

From the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13399990/usage-of-pull-command-in-jgit), you can read more about this problem.

```
private String localPath;
private Repository localRepo;
private Git git;

localPath = "/home/test/git_repo_test";
remotePath = "https://github.com/test/repo_1.git";

try {
    localRepo = new FileRepository(localPath + "/.git");
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();  
}
git = new Git(localRepo);

PullCommand pullCmd = git.pull();
try {
    pullCmd.call();
    PullResult result = pullCmd.call();
    FetchResult fetchResult = result.getFetchResult();
    MergeResult mergeResult = result.getMergeResult();
    mergeResult.getMergeStatus();  // this should be interesting
} catch (GitAPIException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();  
}
```